# How can I instantiate a JRuby class that implements a Java interface in Java

Tags: java, jruby, javax.script

There is a Java interface Job:

```
interface Job{
...
}
```

and a JRuby class SimpleJob that implements it:

```
class SimpleJob
require org.quartz.Job
...
end
```

I need to (from a Java class) instantiate the `SimpleJob` class using the `javax.script.ScriptEngine` class, and get its class object. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"easiest" way is doing an eval :

```
IRubyObject instance = (IRubyObject) rubyEngine.eval("SimpleJob.new");
```

to access the class and "call" it by hand :

```
RubyClass klass = (RubyClass) rubyEngine.eval("SimpleJob");
klass.callMethod("new");
```

NOTE: it's also possible to achieve the same using JRuby's "direct" API :

```
runtime.getClass("SimpleJob").callMethod("new");
```

assuming you obtained a `org.jruby.Ruby` **runtime** instance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can instate it. Why you just dont create a script that does what you want and then use the SciptEngine to execute the script? Like so

```
ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine rubyEngine = m.getEngineByName("jruby");
try {  
  FileReader f = new FileReader("yourscript.rb");
  engine.eval(f);
} catch (javax.script.ScriptException e) {
    ...
}
```

Also take a look at this, maybe it will help you
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/DirectJRubyEmbedding